# NoClassDefFoundError in Android 4.4

Tags: java, android

I am getting this really weird bug that I couldn't find. My app perfectly works on other devices with Lollipop and marshmallow. But it **crashes on Android 4.4**, every device with Android 4.4.

Here's the error log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: se.itmaskinen.android.nativemint.saco16, PID: 3371
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{se.itmaskinen.android.nativemint.saco16/se.itmaskinen.android.nativemint.leadingage.Activity_Init2}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "se.itmaskinen.android.nativemint.leadingage.Activity_Init2" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/se.itmaskinen.android.nativemint.saco16-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/se.itmaskinen.android.nativemint.saco16-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "se.itmaskinen.android.nativemint.leadingage.Activity_Init2" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/se.itmaskinen.android.nativemint.saco16-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/se.itmaskinen.android.nativemint.saco16-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: se.itmaskinen.android.nativemint.leadingage.Activity_Init2
         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
         ... 12 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class "Lse/itmaskinen/android/nativemint/leadingage/Activity_Init2;" not found
         ... 16 more
    11-10 22:40:56.056 2309-2546/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity se.itmaskinen.android.nativemint.saco16/se.itmaskinen.android.nativemint.leadingage.Activity_Init2
```

I already tried renaming the class involved in the error.

I also tried changing from `complete.package.name.leadingage.Activity_Init2` to just `.Activity_Init2`

I also tried cleaning and building the project MILLION TIMES.

Please help. Thanks!

I am using `buildToolsVersion '25'`, `compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22'` and Android Studio version 2.2.2, Gradle 2.14.1

Comment: Suggestion: Try to use the same API for `buildToolsVersion`, `CompileSDKVersion`, `TargetSdkVersion`, and support library (if you use it). In your case, use API 25.

Comment: call old version `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'`

Comment: Now it's giving me this error: `ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lse/itmaskinen/android/nativemint/database/DBCreator;`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya the same problem :(

Comment: set `compileSdkVersion 24`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it's now back to the problem in my question :(

Comment: set `compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"`

Comment: I am gettng errors for package org.apache.http does not exist @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: add `android {

      useLibrar y'org.apache.http.legacy'
  }`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya still the same error from above :(

Answer (score 0):

You should check your armeabi folder .
That crash is caused  by your phone CPU does not match your so

Comment: What should I do please?